# The difference between "she ran a book" and "she published a book"

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between these two sentences:

> "she **ran** a book."

and

> "she **published** a book."

Comment: Perhaps you could edit to clarify which of the two you already understand so people do not waste time and insult you by explaining what you already know

Comment: If she ran a book she was taking bets on some event like a horse race.

Comment: There is no useful answer unless you can give some more details.  The difference is that the first use "ran" and the second uses "published".  It is like asking the difference between "It is a dog" and "It is a cat".

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "run a book" usually means to manage a gambling operation:
[Wordreference.com forums](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/to-run-a-book.2959906/)

> To take bets; to take money and pay out more to those who correctly predicted the outcome.

One who does that is a bookmaker or bookie:
[American Heritage Dictionary "bookmaker"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?id=B5402400)

> 2. One who accepts and pays off bets, as on a horserace. Also called bookie.

"Publish a book" means this:
[American Heritage Dictionary "publish"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=publish)

> 1.a. To prepare and issue (a book, music, or other material) for public distribution, especially for sale.
> b. To prepare and issue a work or works by (an author).